# Unable to retrieve serialized data from database

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

I'm able to update using serialize data into database properly but I am not able to retrieve it properly. Its echoing just Array when I try to unserialize and retrieve it from database.

Here is how I update using serialize:

```
$query ="Update dashboard_widget_users set dashboard_widget_users.configuration='".serialize($tmp)."' where dashboard_widget_users.dsnr_yw_user =12 and dashboard_widget_users.dsnr_dashboard_widget=1";
```

Result:

`a:4:{i:0;s:30:""Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_ohne_Bilder"";i:1;s:22:""Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis"";i:2;s:23:""Fahrzeuge_mit_Fehlern"";i:3;s:19:""Herausforderungen"";}`

This is how I tried to `unserialize()` and retrieve it from database but am not getting any output properly:

```
$config= unserialize($row['configuration']);
echo $config['configuration'];
```

Here is my code:

```
if($param['aktion'] == 'save-widget-vehicle')
{
    $page['register-fahrzeuge'] = array(
        1   => array( 'Fahrzeug','aktiv',$page['script'],''),
        0   => array( 'Edit-Fahrzeug','enabled',$page['script'],'',''), 
    );

        $opts = !empty($param['filterOpts']) ? $param['filterOpts'] : array();

      $tmp = array();
      foreach ($opts as $opt) {
            $tmp[] = '"'.$opt.'"';
      }
      $data = array();

     $query ="UPDATE dashboard_widget_users w SET w.configuration=\"".mysql_real_escape_string(serialize($tmp))."\" WHERE w.dsnr_yw_user =12 AND w.dsnr_dashboard_widget=1";            
     $result = mysql_query($query, $myConnection);

        $html = '<table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div>'.CreateRegister($page['register-news']).'</div>
                        '.CreateMessage().'
                        <div class="cont-liste-verlauf register"> 
                        <table id="fahrzeuge"> 

                                        <tr>
                                    <td>                                        

                                    </td>                               
                            </tr>                               


                        </table>            
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>';


                    $return = array(
            'status' => 1,
            'html'  => $html
        );

    echo json_encode($return);
    die();

     $param['aktion'] = 'get-widget-vehicle';
}


if($param['aktion'] == 'get-widget-vehicle')
{
    $page['register-fahrzeuge'] = array(
        1   => array( 'Fahrzeug','aktiv',$page['script'],''),
        0   => array( 'Edit-Fahrzeug','enabled',$page['script'],'',''), 
    );

                $data = array();

                    $opts = !empty($param['filterOpts']) ? $param['filterOpts'] : array();

                $tmp = array();
                foreach ($opts as $opt) {
                $tmp[] = '"'.$opt.'"';
                }

            $query ='SELECT dashboard_widget_users.configuration
                                         FROM dashboard_widget_users
                                         INNER JOIN yw_user ON dashboard_widget_users.dsnr_yw_user = yw_user.intern
                                         INNER JOIN dashboard_widget ON dashboard_widget_users.dsnr_dashboard_widget = dashboard_widget.id
                                         WHERE dashboard_widget_users.dsnr_yw_user =12 AND dashboard_widget.id =1';  
        $result = mysql_query($query, $myConnection);

      /*while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if($row['name'] == 'Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_mit_und_ohne_Bilder')
        {
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM amo_bilder_live l LEFT JOIN afzdaten a ON l.dsnr_afzdaten = a.dsnr WHERE l.dsnr_afzdaten IS NULL';
            $sql_result=mysql_query($sql);
            //get result...
            // $row['number'] = $result
        }
        $data[] = $row;
    }*/

        $html = '<table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
            <tr>
                <td>
                <div>'.CreateRegister($page['register-fahrzeuge']).'</div>
                '.CreateMessage().'
                <div class="cont-liste-verlauf register"> ';
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $config= unserialize($row['configuration']);
                    //$config= $row['configuration'];               
                    $html .= '<table id="fahrzeuge"> 
                                <a href="amo_fahrzeuge.php"> '. $config .'</a>                  
                    </table>';
                }
            $html .= '</div>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>';

    $return = array(
        'status' => 1,
        'html'  => $html
    );

    echo json_encode($return);
    die();

}
```

Comment: There is no key `configuration` in your serialize data. And why the use of `mysql_escape_string`?

Comment: i am getting multiple values from array and i thought i will use mysql_escape_string while serializing my data

Answer (score 0):

You always escape a string depending on where it is *going* so you use mysqli_real_escape_string() on a value before putting it *into* the database - not when you are retrieving it from the database:

```
 $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
 $config=unserialize($row['config']);
```

You've tagged this with jsonserializer - but you are using PHP serialization here.

Comment: thanks you i made changes now in question as u said but now i am echoing as Array not the results. Can you please tell me why ?

Answer (score 0):

Just need to unserialize that's all. why mysql_escape_string?

if,

```
$dbresult = 'a:4:{i:0;s:30:""Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_ohne_Bilder"";i:1;s:22:""Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis"";i:2;s:23:""Fahrzeuge_mit_Fehlern"";i:3;s:19:""Herausforderungen"";}';
$data = unserialize($dbresult);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: please check the updated question i have tried it but still only getting output as Array not the results...

Comment: Is that result what you print in the question is result from DB? May I know how you are fetching that what is your expectation?

Comment: yes i am fetching result from database.I have stored my array results using serialize option and its stored in database as given in question.But when i try to retrieve it from database i dont want serialize data including all hashes,brackets. But i want actual data like: Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_ohne_Bilder Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis

Comment: i just want to remove this curly braces and all and want to get actual data

Answer (score 0):

```
$query ="UPDATE dashboard_widget_users w SET w.configuration=\"".mysql_real_escape_string(serialize($tmp))."\" WHERE w.dsnr_yw_user =12 AND w.dsnr_dashboard_widget=1";
```

new get-widget-vehicle

```
<?php
if($param['aktion'] == 'get-widget-vehicle')
{
    $page['register-fahrzeuge'] = array(
            1 => array( 'Fahrzeug','aktiv',$page['script'],''),
            0 => array( 'Edit-Fahrzeug','enabled',$page['script'],'',''), 
        );

        $data = array();
        $opts = !empty($param['filterOpts']) ? $param['filterOpts'] : array();

        $tmp = array();
        foreach ($opts as $opt) {
            $tmp[] = '"'.$opt.'"';
        }

        $query ='SELECT w.configuration
                 FROM dashboard_widget_users w
                 INNER JOIN yw_user ON w.dsnr_yw_user = yw_user.intern
                 INNER JOIN dashboard_widget ON w.dsnr_dashboard_widget = dashboard_widget.id
                 WHERE w.dsnr_yw_user =12 AND dashboard_widget.id =1';

        $result = mysql_query($query, $myConnection);
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
            var_dump($row);
        $row = $row[0]; //take first array element as result -- please LIMIT your query!

        $config = $row; //store config string to $config
            var_dump($config);
            die();
        $config = unserialize($config); //unserialize $config

        $html = '<table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
            <tr>
                <td>
                <div>'.CreateRegister($page['register-fahrzeuge']).'</div>
                '.CreateMessage().'
                <div class="cont-liste-verlauf register"> ';
                /*
                //do whatever you want to do with $config
                foreach ($config as $k => $v)
                    echo "$k = $v<br />";
                */
            $html .= '</div>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>';

    $return = array(
        'status' => 1,
        'html'  => $html
    );

    echo json_encode($return);
    die();
}
?>
```

Comment: i tried it its updating data in such way as u told : a:3:{i:0;s:30:""Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_ohne_Bilder"";i:1;s:22:""Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis"";i:2;s:19:""Herausforderungen"";}   But now i want to unserialize it and dont want any curly braces and all only my actualy data like: Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_ohne_Bilder. How to get that ?

Comment: what about echo **$data['Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_ohne_Bilder'];** ?
you can also echo the whole array like this

**foreach ($data as $k=>$v) echo "$k = $v<br />";**

Comment: How can you echo data from database like echo $data['Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_ohne_Bilder']; as you dont know what data are coming from database ? We just have to normalize the data whtever it is coming..

Comment: fetch $row -> access key configuration in $row -> unserialize -> echo
simple as that

Comment: please check the updated question for complete code..in 'save-widget-vehicle' i am trying to update my query..and in 'get-widget vehicle' i am retrieving the query..

Comment: i modified your snippet and added some commentary (see answer above)

Comment: the same output as serialize string as mentioned in my question in Result...Now i am echoing as Array ...

Comment: whats the result of var_dump($config); and var_dump($row);

Comment: where it is var_dump($config) ?

Comment: modified sample for debugging

Comment: it showing an error now but in firebug its not showing where exactly the error is ? when i try to use var_dump($config),var_dump($row) or die() as u suggest it simply not showing anything...

Comment: i dont know why i cant i use var_dump function in my code ?